# Program pauses at loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I've got a simple C program, which loops to get an indefinite amount of numbers from the user (it's a CAS of sorts). I'm working on the program in multiple languages, and while the C++ version works perfectly, the C version stalls at the end of the loop, when the program asks for another user operation, requiring the user to input the operation twice. Here's how the program should work:

> **Enter an operation**
>   4+2
>   **6**
>   **6**+2 // User adds 2 to the previous answer
>   **8**+x // User can continue adding like this indefinitely

Instead, here's what happens:

> **Enter an operation**
>   4+2
>   **6**+2
>   // nothing happens until user enters "+2" again
>   +2
>   **8**+x
>   +x
>   [sum of 8+x]
>   and so on.

I initially thought this pause was caused by the program asking for user input twice, once at the start of the loop, and then at the end before looping. I put an iteration counter in the loop to determine what kind of input the program should get (either `&num1,&op,&num2` or `&op,&num2`). For some reason, that didn't make a difference. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
int opnubmer;
opnumber = 0;

printf("Enter an operation\n");
    while(op != '=')
    {
        if (opnumber == 0)
        {
            scanf("%d%c%d",&num1,&op,&num2);
        }
        else if (opnumber != 0)
        {
            scanf("%s%d",&op,&num2);
        }
        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                num2 += num1;
                break;

            case '-':
                num2 -= num1;
                break;

            case '*':
                num2 *= num1;
                break;

            case '/':
                num2 /= num1;
                break;

            default:
                printf("%s%c%s", "Unknown op: ", op, "\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        printf("Solution: ");
        printf("%d",num2);

        opnumber++;
        num1=num2;
   }
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `scanf` is "difficult" to use with unformatted input (input from users). It was meant for **formatted input**, hence the **f** in its name. I suggest you read user input with `fgets` and parse it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you made a typo in the second `scanf` call, where you used `%s` instead of `%c` to read the `op`.

Furthermore, when using `scanf` to read input, you have to be very careful with whitespace. Trailing whitespace (including newlines) is left on the input stream, so the next time you read from the input stream, the whitespace is the first thing it'll see.

Instead of using `scanf`, use `fgets` to read the input one line at a time into a buffer, and then parse what you need out of that buffer. Eg. :

```
char line[256];
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
sscanf(line, "%d%c%d", &num1, &op, &num2);
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I tried it, and it falls back to `Unknown op: `, without giving the operation.

Comment: @user2129150 use scanf with %d instead of %c

Comment: that's because `scanf` leaves a newline on the input stream. I'll update my answer with that.

Comment: I tried the `fgets` syntax, but this time it doesn't even wait for input; instead, it falls back to `Unknown op: ¿`.

Comment: did you replace every single `scanf` calls with an `fgets`/`sscanf` pair ?

Comment: I missed one `scanf()` call. It works like a charm now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It behaves absolutely fine, when you are not in the first iteration, you are looking for a `string`, even if you fix it with a change to `%c` your program expects only a character and a number not a `number character number` sequence.